# Difference between $model->attributes and $model->setAttributes() in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Whenever I use `$model->attributes=$_POST['Users']` ,it saves Data from User form.

When I use `$model->setAttributes($_POST['Users'])`,it also saves Data from User form.

So please can anyone clarify the difference between the two codes ?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but `setAttributes()` should also run some validation rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the Yii wiki, you can use any of these. With `$model->attributes` you set the variable directly. With `$model->setAttributes()` you set the variable through a so called 'setter method'.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/#hh1

I would use the setter method instead of directly calling the variable, as you can add a line in your setter method, and it would apply to all of its calls, and it would save you from a lot of headache in the future.

Example:

```
class Model {
  public $attributes;

  public function setAttributes($attributes) {
    $this->attributes = $attributes;
  }
  public function getAttributes() {
    return $this->attributes;
  }
}

$model = new Model();
$model->setAttributes("Foo");
echo $model->getAttributes();
$model->setAttributes("Bar");
echo $model->getAttributes();
```

So, now if you would like to make an additional operation on the attribute, you could add it to the `setAttributes()` method, and instead of changing two lines of code, you could change only one.

Example:

```
class Model {
  public $attributes;

  public function setAttributes($attributes) {
    $this->attributes = $attributes . "-Bar";
  }
  public function getAttributes() {
    return $this->attributes;
  }
}

$model = new Model();
$model->setAttributes("Foo");
echo $model->getAttributes();
$model->setAttributes("Bar");
echo $model->getAttributes();
```

Now scale this up to a level, when it would be inconvenient to change thousands of lines of code, instead of changing a couple of setter methods.

Answer (score 3):

With `$this->setAttributes()` you can assign unsafe attributes, using `$this->attributes` you cant.

Assigning unsafe attributes:

```
$this->setAttributes($_POST['Model'], false);
```

More info in: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel/#setAttributes-detail

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer @Marcos.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference.

When you try to assign a property that is not defined as a PHP class property (such as `attributes` here) on a [component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component), Yii by convention calls the similarly-named setter method `setAttributes` instead. If no such method exists an exception is thrown. Since a Yii model is a component and models do not have an `attributes` property, the setter method is called even when you use the first form.

All of this is also [explained in detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#defining-and-using-a-component-property) in the manual.

Comment: Please do include the necessary parts of the links in your answer as links are known to go dead over a certain period of time .

Comment: I meant the examples mentioned there .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder: I don't feel they are necessary. In any case, there are other answers that do have examples so I would just be duplicating. Go upvote them! :-)

Comment: @Marcos: There is no difference if you do what the question says, which is what I am answering. If you don't do exactly what the question says then technically there is another difference too: setting a property is case-insensitive, calling a method is case-sensitive. It was not my intent to provide all the information that is already in the manual or to cover arbitrary changes to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Users']// means setting value of property directly while
$model->setAttributes($_POST['Users']) //is method or function which is indirectly set value of $model->attributes property;
```

Lets take an example

```
  class Model{
        public $attributes;


         public function setAttributes($att){
             $this->attributes=$att;

        }


  }

            //Now the value of $attributes can be set by two way


 $model = new Model();
 $model->attributes=$value; // 1st way
 $model->setAttributes($value); //2nd way
```

Comment: This example is completely wrong and misses the point. Yii models inherit code that makes them work differently. There is no `$attributes` property.

Comment: This is not Yii. Its general concept of OPP PHP and example is not Yii code its only general example

Comment: But the question is specifically about Yii, which is why this misses the point.

Comment: Yes but problem is related to general OPP PHP  concept.Any body who has no idea about Yii but OPP PHP can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. array_merge used to merge attributes, if set later